# Accuracy loss when converting a tuple of floats into an array in python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, precision

I have some problems with the accuracy when I convert a tuple or list of floats into an array with the 'f' typecode, but with the 'd' typecode it runs "correctly".

For example:

```py
import array

a = (2.16, -22.4, 95.12, -63.47, -0.02, 1245.2)
b = array.array('f', a)
print(b)
# array('f', [2.1600000858306885, -22.399999618530273, 95.12000274658203, -63.470001220703125, -0.019999999552965164, 1245.199951171875])

c = array.array('d', a)
print(c)
# array('d', [2.16, -22.4, 95.12, -63.47, -0.02, 1245.2])
```

As you can see, the array c contains the same numbers as the tuple a, but the array b has accuracy problems.

However both `type(b[0])` and `type(c[0])` results in `<class 'float'>`.

Comment: Hi ! Can you add some details about whet you expect ? It seems your post isn't finished yet.

Comment: I expect the array 'b' results in just as like the array 'c'

Comment: In fact both conversions to double or float have accuracy problems, but you don't see them in the double case because of how the output is formatted. Try `print('{:4.20}'.format(b[0]))` and `print('{:4.20}'.format(c[0]))` to see the far decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no accuracy-loss in the way you may suspect here, it's a case of "[Representation Error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error)".

The literal value `2.16` does not have an exact representation as a float; after parsing it is stored as `0x400147AE147AE148`, because Python [always uses double precision](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) (see `Numbers.real`) to represent floats.

The value is then converted to `0x400A3D71` (in case of `f`) or stays the same (is case of `d`). These values correspond to 2.1600000858306884765625 and 2.16000000000000014210854715202, both of which are the most accurate representation of the literal `2.16` one could get. The loss of precision from the original `2.16` is inevitable because `2.16` simply does not exist as a precise value.

What you are seeing in the string representation is the interpreter rounding the underlying float/double to a near value if the loss in precision due to that rounding [is considered acceptable](https://bugs.python.org/issue1580). The underlying values are as close to `2.16` as they could possibly get in both cases, just their string representation is different.